# Failed to extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have this error with my Spring Data/JPA project:

```
SQL Error: -206, SQLState: 42703 
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=MYDONNEE0_.MYCONNEX_IDCON, DRIVER=4.19.26 
SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098 
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;MYDONNEE0_.MYCONNEX_IDCON, DRIVER=4.19.26 
SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098 
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;MYDONNEE0_.MYCONNEX_IDCON, DRIVER=4.19.26 
Enter: my.package.test.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with argument[s] = [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: my.package.test.repository.entity.MYconnex["MYdonnees"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: my.package.test.repository.entity.MYconnex["MYdonnees"])] 
Exit: my.package.test.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with result = <500 Internal Server Error,my.package.test.web.rest.errors.ErrorDTO@70b511c1,{}>
```

I search, but i don't find a problem with my entity.

MYconnex :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="MYconnex.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM MYconnex u")
public class MYconnex implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long IDCON;

    private String key;

    private Timestamp dateconnex;

    private String mel;

    private int tel;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to MYdonnees
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="MYconnex")
    private List<MYdonnees> MYdonnees;

    //Getter and setter
}
```

MYdonnees :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="MYdonnees.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM MYdonnees u")
@Table(name="MYdonnees")
public class MYdonnees implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long idata;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="\"DATA\"")
    private String data;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to MYconnex
    @ManyToOne
    private MYconnex MYconnex;

    public MYdonnees() {
    }

    //Getter and Setter

}
```

My CrudRepository :

```
public interface ADRESSRepository extends CrudRepository<ADRESS, Integer> {
}
```

The DataBase :

[image]

I think the problem come from the entity, but I can't find this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a bidirectional relation of an enitity to JSON. You get an endless loop try to add @JsonIgnore to break the loop on your bi-directional association

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  private Udsaconnex udsaconnex;

@jsonsetter  
public void setUdsaconnex(Udsaconnex udsaconnex){
     this.udsaconnex = udsaconnex;
}
```

Comment: What's the new problem ? just on your Udsadonnees class  on the udsaconnex setter add @jsonsetter

Comment: Does it perform once and then breaks the loop or does it prevent from looking in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, here is what worked for me:

In the parent class:

```
@JsonIgnore // to break endless loop in bi-directional association
public List<Udsaconnex> getUdsadonnees() {
    return udsadonnees;
}
```

In the child class:

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "idconnex") // You must specify the join column.
 private Udsaconnex udsaconnex;
```

These two changes will resolve your problem.